# Calculating NTFS $MFT start cluster from bytes in boot sector

Tags: windows, hex, byte, ntfs

I'm wondering how windows interprets the 8 bytes that define the starting cluster for the $MFT. Convering the 8 bytes to decimal using a calculator doesn't work, luckily WinHex has a calculator which displays the correct value, though I don't know how it's calculated:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad0bn.jpg

The picture above shows WinHeX data interpreter showing the correct amount. So my question is, how does '00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00' equate to '786432'.

I saw another user had a similar question about the number of bytes per sector, which was answered by someone that it was down to a byte being base 256. But that doesn't really help me figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: 0x00000C is 786432 (12 * 65536) when read as a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have to do some research on little-endian integers